# R: Find most recent data that fulfills conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, lag

I have a dataframe in long format of games, their date, and whether the respective team has won. It has the following structure:

```
   GAME_DATE_EST GAME_ID  TEAM_ID    WIN  
   <date>        <int>    <int>      <lgl>
 1 2015-06-16    41400406 1610612739 FALSE
 2 2015-06-16    41400406 1610612744 TRUE 
 3 2015-06-14    41400405 1610612744 TRUE 
 4 2015-06-14    41400405 1610612739 FALSE
 5 2015-06-11    41400404 1610612739 FALSE
 6 2015-06-11    41400404 1610612744 TRUE 
 7 2015-06-09    41400403 1610612739 TRUE 
 8 2015-06-09    41400403 1610612744 FALSE
 9 2015-06-07    41400402 1610612744 FALSE
10 2015-06-07    41400402 1610612739 TRUE
```

For each row, I need the most recent previous game that fulfills different conditions. For example, I want a new column with the GAME_ID of the most previous win for the respective team, one with the GAME_ID for the most previous loss, etc.

The only solution I found so far is with this function and using it with `rowwise()` but it takes ages to complete:

```
get_most_recent_win = function(df, team_id, date) {
  temp = subset(df, WIN & TEAM_ID == team_id & GAME_DATE_EST < date,
                select = c("GAME_ID", "GAME_DATE_EST"))
  
  if (nrow(temp) > 0) {
    return(temp[which.max(temp$GAME_DATE_EST), "GAME_ID"])
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

games_longer[1:50, ] %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(most_recent_win = get_most_recent_win(., TEAM_ID, GAME_DATE_EST)) %>% 
  select(GAME_DATE_EST, GAME_ID, most_recent_win, TEAM_ID, WIN)
```

Generally, what would be the tidiest and most efficient way to solve such problems?

Here is the data for you to try:

```
structure(list(GAME_DATE_EST = structure(c(16602, 16602, 16600, 
16600, 16597, 16597, 16595, 16595, 16593, 16593, 16590, 16590, 
16582, 16582, 16581, 16581, 16580, 16580, 16579, 16579), class = "Date"), 
    GAME_ID = c(41400406L, 41400406L, 41400405L, 41400405L, 41400404L, 
    41400404L, 41400403L, 41400403L, 41400402L, 41400402L, 41400401L, 
    41400401L, 41400315L, 41400315L, 41400304L, 41400304L, 41400314L, 
    41400314L, 41400303L, 41400303L), TEAM_ID = c(1610612739L, 
    1610612744L, 1610612744L, 1610612739L, 1610612739L, 1610612744L, 
    1610612739L, 1610612744L, 1610612744L, 1610612739L, 1610612744L, 
    1610612739L, 1610612744L, 1610612745L, 1610612739L, 1610612737L, 
    1610612745L, 1610612744L, 1610612739L, 1610612737L), WIN = c(FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: please clarify the meaning of "most previous". Doo you mean the more recent one? Or older match that meets the criteria?

Comment: please also share the data. You can paste the output of `dput(df)`

Comment: if it is too large, use `head()`. Like in `dput(head(df, 10))`

Comment: Data is added to the post. So I want to know what is the ID of the last game the current team has won before the date of the current row. Just as someone saying for each row: "Hi, the team is playing today. Which is the last game they have won?"

Comment: So the function always returns an older game than itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, arrange by `GAME_DATE_EST`
Then, create a variable with the GAME_ID of the `lag`ed wins, filled with NAs. Then, `fill`, replacing the NAs with the last valid values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df |> 
    arrange(GAME_DATE_EST, TEAM_ID) |> 
    group_by(TEAM_ID) |> 
    mutate(last_win = if_else(lag(WIN), lag(GAME_ID), NA)) |> 
    fill(last_win) |> 
    ungroup()
    

# A tibble: 20 × 5
   GAME_DATE_EST  GAME_ID    TEAM_ID WIN   last_win
   <date>           <int>      <int> <lgl>    <int>
 1 2015-05-24    41400303 1610612739 TRUE        NA
 2 2015-05-24    41400303 1610612737 FALSE       NA
 3 2015-05-25    41400314 1610612745 TRUE        NA
 4 2015-05-25    41400314 1610612744 FALSE       NA
 5 2015-05-26    41400304 1610612739 TRUE  41400303
 6 2015-05-26    41400304 1610612737 FALSE       NA
 7 2015-05-27    41400315 1610612744 TRUE        NA
 8 2015-05-27    41400315 1610612745 FALSE 41400314
 9 2015-06-04    41400401 1610612744 TRUE  41400315
10 2015-06-04    41400401 1610612739 FALSE 41400304
11 2015-06-07    41400402 1610612744 FALSE 41400401
12 2015-06-07    41400402 1610612739 TRUE  41400304
13 2015-06-09    41400403 1610612739 TRUE  41400402
14 2015-06-09    41400403 1610612744 FALSE 41400401
15 2015-06-11    41400404 1610612739 FALSE 41400403
16 2015-06-11    41400404 1610612744 TRUE  41400401
17 2015-06-14    41400405 1610612744 TRUE  41400404
18 2015-06-14    41400405 1610612739 FALSE 41400403
19 2015-06-16    41400406 1610612739 FALSE 41400403
20 2015-06-16    41400406 1610612744 TRUE  41400405
```

Comment: This is not working yet for me. If the team has won the current game, it returns the current game id. It should return the id of the game the team has won before that. Also, could you explain what the fill() does exactly here?

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: please check now

Comment: The intermediary object created by `mutate` has the lagged GAME_IDs for the wins, with NA s for all non-wins. `tidyr::fill()` replaces the NAs with the `last valid value`, carrying their value forward, as intended.

Comment: That's clever! That was the piece I was missing in my previous attempts with a lag solution. Thank you very much, it looks good now on first sight :)

Comment: glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going row-wise, you can use the `dplyr` package to compute vectors more efficiently:

```
library(dplyr)

games_longer %>%
  arrange(TEAM_ID, GAME_DATE_EST) %>%
  group_by(TEAM_ID) %>%
  mutate(most_recent_win = ifelse(WIN, lag(GAME_ID))) %>%
  select(GAME_DATE_EST, GAME_ID, most_recent_win, TEAM_ID, WIN)
```

I used `arrange()` to sort by `TEAM_ID` and `GAME_DATE_EST` just to have it organized in order. Used `group_by()` to group rows by `TEAM_ID` and this will later set me up to perform operations on these groups of rows with `mutate()`. `lag()` retrieves the `GAME_ID` of the previous row (ie. last win) since the rows have already been arranged in chronological order.

In this case, if the `WIN` = `FALSE`, it will fill the `most_recent_win` column with `NA`.

Comment: Thank your for the help. This is a solution I had tried earlier. Unfortunately, it returns NA if the previous game of the team was lost. Instead, it should return the ID of the earlier game where the team had won. In the accepted answer, this has been solved by using fill().